# Structures and arrays in C

Tags: c

I must create a program focusing on the use of structures.

The program will ask the user to enter the number of students for whom he will later add specific information (name, surname, average grade).

For some reason, when I start the the program, I enter the number of students i want, after that I enter the info of the first student and then the program terminates.

Here's what I've tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
    {
        char *name;
        char *surname;
        float *average;
    };

    void inputs(struct student *a, int size);


int main()
{
    int size;

    printf("Enter the number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    struct student *data;
    data = (struct student *)malloc(size*sizeof(struct student));
    if(data==NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory. The program will now terminate.");
        return -1;
    }

    inputs (data, size);

    return 0;
}

void inputs(struct student *a, int size)
{
    int j=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("Enter the name of the student number %d: ", j+1);
        scanf("%s", a->name);
        printf("Enter the surname of the student number %d: ", j+1);
        scanf("%s", a->surname);
        printf("Enter the average grade of the student number %d: ", j+1);
        scanf("%f", a->average);
        j++;
        a++;
        }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the cause of your crash, but note that you always only write values to the first student in the array.

Comment: you haven't allocated memory for name/surname variables inside of struct

Comment: @IłyaBursov But as far as I know, the way I've done this, the system allocates the needed memory as the user types in the characters. For example, if I write int *ptr=john  the program will automatically allocate memory for 5 characters including the \0.

Comment: @Giannis `the system allocates the needed memory as the user types in the characters` this is false.

Comment: @Giannis type is pointer, so it will allocate only 4 bytes for pointer, system does not know how many symbols you will store in it

Comment: @PatrickRoberts My book says that this way the word is stored somewhere in the memory and the pointer points to the first character of the word.

Comment: @Giannis your program must explicitly allocate the memory that `scanf()` writes to. `scanf()` does not allocate memory.

Comment: @Giannis book is correct, word will be stored somewhere in memory, but this memory is allocated by you

Comment: @IłyaBursov so in this case how to i allocate that memory?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts and how do i do that?

Comment: @Giannis it should be something like `a[i].name = malloc(MAX_NAME);`

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student
    {
        char name[30];
        char surname[30];
        float average;
    };

    void inputs(struct student *a, int size);


int main()
{
    int size;
    int i=0; // we need i
    char string[100];

    printf("Enter the number of students: ");
    // scanf can be tricky lets use fgets
    fgets( string , 99 , stdin );
        size= atoi(string);

    struct student **data; // array of struct

    // get memory for the pointers to pointer
    data=(struct student **) calloc( size , sizeof(char *));
    // now each struct need space
    for( i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
    {
    data[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    if(data[i]==NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory. The program will now terminate.");
        return -1;
    }// end if
    }// end for loop

    // input each student
    for( i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
    inputs (data[i], i );

    return 0;
}

void inputs(struct student *a, int num)
{
    int j=0;
    char string[100];

    // scanf can be tricky lets use fgets
    printf("Enter the name of the student number %d: ", num+1);
    fgets(a->name, 29, stdin);
    printf("Enter the surname of the student number %d: ", num+1);
    fgets( a->surname , 29, stdin);
    printf("Enter the average grade of the student number %d: ", num+1);
    fgets( string , 99, stdin);
    a->average=atof(string);

}
```

Comment: This code works for some loosely defined value of "works". `fgets` stores the newline character in the buffer. Do you know anyone named `John\n`? It also reads one character less than the size of each `char` array allows, for no reason at all. And why an array of pointers?!